# Python check json to ensure field is not present

Tags: python

I have a python function that I want to check if a certain field is present in the json that is passed through. Essentially I want to throw an error if the field exists.

I have something that works, but doesn't look good so I think there is a better solution:

```
def check_groups(names):
    json_names = json.loads(names)
    for i in json_names:
        try:
            #check to make sure no groups have been passed through
            if(i['groups']):
                print('in if')
                raise Exception()
        except TypeError:
            #this means there is no groups in the json so all is ok
            print('ok')
        except Exception:
            raise Exception('Do not pass through groups')
```

As you can see, it isn't great logically and I obviously have to have a line of code after except TypeError (in this case `print('ok')` which I don't really want/need to do.

Essentially, if the json has a field called `groups`, I want to throw an error. If not, just continue.

The json is simple, here is an example of how it looks with the unwanted field provided:

```
[{"field_1": ["$.id"], "groups": "ABC"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
def check_groups(names):
    json_names = json.loads(names)
    for i in json_names:
        if 'groups' in i:
            raise AttributeError('Do not pass through groups')
        else:
            print('ok')
```

You can easily test if a key is in a dict using the `in` keyword.